# unity android plugin c#- can't find dll file

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've successfully build up the dll file in UNITY (ASSET->PLUGINS-> ANDROID-> DLL FILE) but UNITY engine CAN'T bring up the dll file. Why is that? which step did I miss?

DLL file supports window and android, and as per checking in window it perfectly worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You should .aar or jat file in to ASSET->PLUGINS-> ANDROID, if you want use(or call) dll file's function you have to dll imort or built to .so file

Comment: I did set the file as per above but the script can't bring up the dll file. The dll file is created in C++ but our script  is C#, what do we have to do? Advise the code to write down in script.

Comment: Checkout this Documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/kr/530/Manual/NativePlugins.html

Comment: Already try that code, Still not working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLTDD.png

Comment: shoul you try to erase "lib" into dll library name?

Comment: Tried, but still can't bring up the dll file.